# How can I access array field of an object in TypeScript? Type 'unknown' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, iterator, destructuring

I have a helper function which updates the form based on the fieldname, e.g. if name, then form.name will be updated. If user[0].name, then name of index 0 of form.users will be updated. However I'm facing an error and it is simplified by the code below:

```
const example: Record<string, unknown> = {
    'a': 'haha',
    'b': [1,2,3],
};
const str = 'b.haha';
const tokens: string[] = str.split(".");
if (typeof example[tokens[0]][Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
    const c = [...example[tokens[0]];
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0NYMRALSD5UCPSAIMjcAA8VMonGY-C48QGEk4AD5QABeUAAb0UJRKAHIGHLGXKHA45bwZbK5dIlaAANoARl4ACZeABmAC6GoAvgBuRQUqlXVDYiXagKqxX2x00dDxFEFZ3c5h6i3ioMBQQLeQACgARAE4wBKe0I0Ax1DtIk0unuPV+gN6gAMFoteuIeEQwOgAXk3zq8DIYbFLdAcuSXFg9UacqTUs1JR9JnDeoCY5z9Pz8H9lOLpft1uCxRwzQ8ZC8iEbzmB7F9d0YPPYDGYkH4sGg6kSDGBehEXjjAFFVrT6YI40lsXHwA5UHLhAA5SAJATYoAHkvjId5BFPLRICOVBHAUVxpDwUAnE3HRhiwfQUAQRBoWES4vkkRtohEAwOGxBYmFYDgeCCEogA)

I can't solve this Type 'unknown' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set the second generic argument of `Record` to `unknown`. In your case you probably want to it to be `any` instead:

```
const example: Record<string, any> = { // <- change is in this line
    'a': 'haha',
    'b': [1,2,3],
};
const str = 'b.haha';
const tokens: string[] = str.split(".");

if (typeof example[tokens[0]][Symbol.iterator] === 'function') {
    const c = [...example[tokens[0]];
    console.log(c);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAuGAlOUAJwBMAeaIgSzAHMAaGJMATwD4YBeGAbxgHp%20MMgFoYwABbNacGFQhywMKBPkwMNOACgYumAHIk%203PqlT99HXv0AjYzADaARnoAmegGYAupYC%20Abi1QSFhKLgMbADozI0Dg6GUQAGs4SFxKGloHL3DKSIhMKigACgAiSNKASkCtKgAzGGKoFjQ4EAbEVEw4Byhk1IgHAAYvLwcAZRYUGxAMSKK4IiQ%20ohzOdYM6gFcwYCgqcH1K3itdeNhgcIdIm870LF7%20yGHRwL1xcAhZuEiMEFpisBqlpfFogA)

The fundamental difference between `unknown` and `any` IMO is that you need to cast variables of type `unknown` actively, while you can do anything with variables of type `any`. This makes `unknown` a bit more safe since you get errors at compile time if you try to do something with a `unknown` variable although the code doesn't know what it is at that line.

Personally I would keep the `unknown` and actually let typescript do it's magic with [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), which automatically casts `c` to `any[]`:

```
const example: Record<string, unknown> = {
    'a': 'haha',
    'b': [1,2,3],
};
const str = 'b.haha';
const tokens: string[] = str.split(".");

const value = example[tokens[0]];

if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    const c = [...value];
    console.log(c);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAuGAlOUAJwBMAeaIgSzAHMAaGAVzAGswQB3MAPhgF4YAbwBQMcTADkSSbkkALJIsn0xEyQCNZMANoBGegCZ6AZgC6qgL4BuEaEixKAqRoB0i5bfvQYUEKzhIXEoaWh0zZ0pXCEwqKAAKACJXRIBKWztwHwA3JAwmOGdEVEw4HT8AyB0ABjMzDKoAMxh4gEEiIiQAT1cqCHbOrvjc-LhU1OE1cW9YYGcdV0WRgvqpmG8QLFcMEFp44HSRSxEgA)

You might want to read up the docs about [`unknown` and how it compares to `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

Comment: …and if `Array.isArray` is not enough since you really need to work with arbitrary iterables, I'd write it [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwIYFsAOAbOAuGAlOUAJwBMAeaIgSzAHMAaGAVzAGswQB3MAPhgF4YAbwBQMcTADkSSbkkALJIsn0xEyQCNZMANoBGegCZ6AZgC6qgL4BuEaEixKAqRoB0i5bfvQYUEKzhIXEoaWh0zZ0pXCEwqKAAKACJXRIBKWztwHwA3JAwmOGdEVEw4HT8AyB0ABjMzDKoAMxh43PzCgDIO3wBPNDgQZta8gpgkCBgASSg4IiQNLDIWdi5eVJ0AZR6UDRAMVzjZpD8iCP5BSUaWYCgqcElU4TVxb1hgZx1XL7bR8amZuYLOBLNgcbg8erPGDePZwVwYEC0eLAdIiSwiIA)